# Tmux 2.0 "pane_current_path" not working on CentOS

Tags: tmux

Tmux 2.0 on my CentOS always goes to the home directory when creating new pane or window. I have added these lines in `.tmux.conf` but still not working after restarting tmux:

```
bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Another similar problem is that I use `tmux-resurrect` to restore saved session, and all restarted panes go to home.

Answer (score 1):

According to <strike>this Q&A</strike>, you can replace `#{pane_current_path}` with `$PWD`.

It works on my CentOS 7 with tmux 1.8.

NOTE: the Q&A link had no answer and tries to get folks to change browser settings. It's been removed.

Comment: I should confess that this is not a direct answer to your question. But my reputation is too low to let me post it as a comment.

Comment: Still not working : (

Comment: The Q&A link in the above answer doesn't link to relevant info.  It actually goes to an insecure site (itsprite.com), which mucks with your browser's search settings.